# Does anybody know why Yahoo! OpenID login with DotNetOpenAuth stopped working?

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

Yesterday I realised that Yahoo! OpenID login with DotNetOpenAuth wasn't working anymore on my site. Then I came to StackOverflow and tried to log-in here. Same problem.

Is this a temporary Yahoo! problem or is it a DotNetOpenAuth problem?

I tried using version 3.4.2 as well as the latest verstion, 3.4.6. I don't know what version does StackOverflow use.

**EDIT**

The details of what happens is the following (in both my site and StackOverflow)

1. I start a request do Yahoo OpenID IdP
2. Yahoo asks me to login
3. I log in successfully
4. The browser requests the following page and then gets stuck there:

https://open.login.yahoo.com/openid/op/start?z=Fi9ONwS5_ujGQwM.JCJN1IyY.5w.vlV7Ggr1yu..tHIkgZPpcVu68UMDlEWer5J9.mAVLddDMuOY8S5RZY31D3id.h7GMHHrgUT6RzniHCpAIj09Xrv5yAH2ltYe4Ubr9lvUu2MksoFCdBKfq7XjKALCT4Ln_ziCs9tQRAkHUDk4NdJqypZ.h16i8pnoUZIYXeX3XMLum4Xtk2ZdVr4CLNrIZWHN.Qxz3_GdG.P4hv1_ynq936zVeARvJZRB3EWhlXtX79eFF3d.JmUG.2zPAHa8L9UAbV6fug8r7qzYSLhhV2rNvhozoa5JuyZv5RY6jDFTeuG2NRv6KVNNi5iIrPA.j_KbjssQfGptofYct759pYkzEG_Adm0Jyo_RAER_MtXEXvWdlpffaL7q5ZEpglWTzw_Om7hYOB40WZuYVqXsMYtkSxGtOmk-&.scrumb=DcjHdwTmC5j

After the browser requests this page it does not return to my site neither to Stackoverflow. Either my site and Stackoverflow log successfully to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I just logged into SO with Yahoo then - worked fine.

Comment: very strange. I'm gonna try with a browser other than FF

Comment: Michael, you probably was able to log in because there was already a Yahoo! cookie on your browser. Try logging out from SO with the option "Logout Everywhere" and than try to log in again. Chances are that you are not going to answer me back after that :)

Comment: :/ I can't log on Yahoo on any browser, neither here on SO or my application. Thank you for your feedback though

Comment: Just tested Yahoo openid with dotnetopenauth in our application and it is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Ciwee, You can try Yahoo! login out yourself with a DotNetOpenAuth RP here at this [interop testing page](http://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx).

I suspect what may have happened is perhaps your site has an XRDS page (very likely since you're testing with Yahoo!) and perhaps that XRDS page is missing an entry for your login page.  Or perhaps even more likely, that XRDS file has your login page URL written using a particular capitalization and the one in your browser as you're logging in uses a different capitalization.  If so, you can test that that is the problem by typing in the login URL yourself in the browser exactly as it appears in your site's XRDS file and see if it works that time.

Comment: Andrew. Thank you for replying. Actually I am not aware of my site having a XRDS file. I actually don't even know what it is. I'll check as soon as possible. Meanwhile, I have updated my question with details of what is happening. I would appreciate if you take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid the link you added to the question isn't helpful to anyone without your login.  Have you tried logging into the interop testing page I linked to in my answer?  I'd be very interested to hear the result.  Also, if you could please include the Yahoo! claimed id that you're trying to log in with, and the RP you're trying to log into, I could investigate further.